# check if webpage is public or private using a js request

Tags: javascript

using vanilla JS, i need to know if someone is using my chrome extension on a private webpage or a public webpage.

example of public webpage

```
https://ww.facebook.com/home
```

example of private webpage

```
https://ww.facebook.com/account/settings
```

Are you able to figure out if a webpage is accessible by everyone or login permissions

what i have

```
let xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'www.facebok.com/account/settings');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  let res = xhr.state;

  //res == 503? 

};
xhr.send();
```

However, i think that since my app runs on their browser, their session will be saved and it will return a false positive.

Comment: What are private and public web pages? E.g. is a web page in my network private or public even though I don't need to login but it's not accessible from outside.

Comment: `https://ww.facebook.com/home` gives *very* different content depending on if you are logged in or not so it isn't clear how public it is.

Comment: @ThomasSablik if my request was redirected because of a 503 or 403 error than it isn't for the public, that user was logged in to access that page. heres an example from my fb, https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=timeline&privacy_source=timeline_gear_menu. it will redirect you

Comment: @Quentin true, but as long as the url is consistent that should be fine

Comment: Angular redirects you without 503 or 403 but the pages are private.

Comment: You need to add the scheme to your XHR-Request (https:// in front)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of checking that for "normal" websites.
Some might in fact return a proper status code, but others (like Facebook) won't and will instead render the same 200 (OK) status page for every URL and handle the login/redirects internally via JavaScript. (This is oversimplified for the sake of this example)

You will have to write separate detection algorithms for every page you want to check.

Comment: google is able to do it, there are millions of webpages that they can reach but billions that are private due to privacy. i only need the bool that sepperates the two

Comment: Ok, the account/settings page you can detect, it returns 404 if you're not logged in.
But every public-when-logged-in page of Facebook is indiscernable from the status code alone.
If you open facebook.com/username while not logged in, it will return 200 OK and show the login box, but otherwise will show the profile of username.

Comment: @DigitalPain — Google index the pages their bot visits. They don't use a browser extension to do it.